# need to extract string from a string

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have:

```
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-7.3.918-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Format is:

```
cachedir               package     packageVersion packageRelease architecture extesnion
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ vim-runtime 7.3.754        1              x86_64       pkg.tar.xz
/var/cache/pacman/pkg/ vim         7.3.918        2              x86_64       pkg.tar.xz
```

So Id like to end up with being able to extract any on of those from the original string
*Packages can have hyphens in their name

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: Are you sure version numbers can't also start with non-numeric strings like `alpha`?

Comment: Sorry, version numbers could contain text as you said

Comment: @JR93 check my answer. if version number does not *start* with something like `alpha` it will work. This is not likely for gnu packages and it is the most I can do for you

Comment: Also, a package name can contain a digit. e.g. `libstdc++6`. `libstdc++6` further has versioning. e.g. on my ubuntu system, I have `libstdc++6` version `4.7.3-1ubuntu1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename` together with `sed` :

```
basename "/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz" \
| sed 's/\([a-z\-]*\)\-\(.*\)/\1/i'
```

Output:

```
vim-runtime  # or ..
vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

```
$ cachedir=$(dirname /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz)
$ printf '%s\n' "$cachedir"
/var/cache/pacman/pkg

$ basename=$(basename /var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz)
$ printf '%s\n' "$basename"
vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

$ IFS=- read -a components <<< "$basename"
$ printf '%s\n' "${components[@]}"
vim
runtime
7.3.754
1
x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

$ printf '%s\n' "${components[-1]}"
x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

$ extension="${components[-1]#*.}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$extension"
pkg.tar.xz

$ architecture="${components[-1]%%.*}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$architecture"
x86_64

$ packageRelease="${components[-2]%%.*}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$packageRelease"
1

$ packageVersion="${components[-3]}"
$ printf '%s\n' "$packageVersion"
7.3.754

$ package=$(echo "${components[@]:0:$((${#components[@]} - 3))}" | tr -s ' ' '-')
$ printf '%s\n' "$package"
vim-runtime
```

Comment: Well, but read the question again I'm sure you'll see the problem for yourself. Your answer is not suited for an automated solution, as you don't know how many parts belong to the package name and how many to the version number. It could be `vim` or `vim-runtime` or even (imaginal) `vim-runtime-dev` . The problem here was to find a solution that can handle this

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
var='/var/cache/pacman/pkg/vim-runtime-7.3.754-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz'; basename ${var%%-[0-9]*}
```